# How to Enable Specific List View Item's click listener

Tags: android, list, listview, onitemclicklistener

In my Application I am Getting data from parse in which some rows Contain Description of Employees and some Not.
I want to make that Happen that if description is not available on Parse of one Items then that list item can't be clicked or can perform `onItemClick` function.

Or Only those can be clicked those have `Description` which i am getting from Parse.

I really have no idea how to achieve this, is this thing can be possible in Android.

I've done all other work getting data from parse and showing in Activity
but Have no Idea About it.
Any Help please

my Whole Class Code is Given Below

```
public class FragmentActivity_DayFirst extends Fragment implements
    OnItemClickListener {
Bitmap bmp;
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
AgendaListAdapter adapter2;
Fragment fr;
FragmentManager fm;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private List<GetSet> agendaList = new ArrayList<GetSet>();
List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment__dayfirst,
            container, false);
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

    return view;
}

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading Details of 1st Day");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog
                .setMessage("Wait.. It May Take a while depending on your Bandwidth");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Agendas");
        query.whereEqualTo("day", "August 7th, 2015");
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
            if (ob != null) {
                for (ParseObject agendas : ob) {

                    // ParseFile image = (ParseFile)
                    // complain.get("imageURL");
                    GetSet agendaGetSet = new GetSet();
                    agendaGetSet.setStartTime((String) agendas
                            .get("startTime"));
                    Log.v("post", (String) agendas.get("startTime"));
                    agendaGetSet
                            .setEndTime((String) agendas.get("endTime"));
                    Log.v("category", (String) agendas.get("endTime"));
                    agendaGetSet.setEventTitle((String) agendas
                            .get("description"));
                    Log.v("post", (String) agendas.get("description"));

                    agendaList.add(agendaGetSet);
                }
            } else {
                Log.v("post", "No Results");
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.v("post", "After query post");
        listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.firstlistview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter2 = new AgendaListAdapter(getActivity(), agendaList);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter2);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Item Click Listener for the listview
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout) linearLayoutParent
                        .getChildAt(0);
                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                RelativeLayout relativeLayoutChild = (RelativeLayout) linearLayoutParent
                        .getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the Country TextView
                TextView tv_title = (TextView) relativeLayoutChild
                        .getChildAt(0);
                TextView startTime = (TextView) linearLayoutChild
                        .getChildAt(0);
                TextView endTime = (TextView) linearLayoutChild
                        .getChildAt(1);

                String mTitle = tv_title.getText().toString();
                String mstartTime = startTime.getText().toString();

                String mendTime = endTime.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EventDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
                intent.putExtra("starttime", mstartTime);
                intent.putExtra("endtime", mendTime);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        mTitle + " " + mstartTime + " " + mendTime,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Hey Asad Please Post the Code for that

Comment: @RajanBhavsar refresh to view the code
and for click listener i have no idea how to do it

Comment: You have to set up the tag as true with Each Listview Item and If there is not having the description for that Item then set to false for that item and when click on that You have to check the Tag for that Item if it is true then run your code else not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whay you can do in your adapter class is to override below function

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {


  // here you can implement logic and can return true and false
  // if you will return true then row will be clickable 
  // if you return false the row will be not clickable        

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how can i use it
I am getting data from parse that is  a description but i am not showing it in listview so i can't get its position.
but if description from parse is null then list item can't be clicked to see the description
but if description is not null then click will be enabled so user can click and see the description

Comment: @AsadMehmood In your adapter class "AgendaListAdapter" implement that function and in that function if the specific objext is null the return false else return true

Comment: Thank you So much Finally I got your point Problem solved Thank you Buddy @Moubeen Farooq Khan